# Пути к исходным файлам в бинарном файле (so)

Tags: clang

Как убрать пути к исходным файлам в бинарном файле (so)?
Может есть какой-то флаг в clang?

```
/home/user/build/folder
...
/home/user/build/folder/file.cpp
```

Comment: команду strip для бинарника с консоли пробовали? (это правда для линукса, для других осей не знаю). Либо компилировать без поддержки отладки (убрать флаги -g, -ggdb и подобные).

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось у linker есть параметр *-s*.
Ответ найден здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916157/is-it-possible-for-gcc-clang-to-link-into-executable-while-stripping-all-the-deb

---

*Strip* - спасибо, работает.